# SSL Certificate and WordPress

Tags: ssl

One of my clients has decided to install an SSL certificate for his website/domain. I have developed a WP website for them it's ready to be deployed. We are currently accessing it via the IP address and it works fine. Normally I just change the URL settings via admin (2 options) and run a search and replace throughout the database, and that's all that's needed.

Should I be doing anything else for SSL? I assume the URL should also start with https:// in the admin settings right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to hardcode anything and/or alter database entries. I'd highly recommend you'd check out the following plugin: [WordPress HTTPS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/) - it's quite versatile and will handle everything for you.

Comment: What about the home URL option should I set it to https://myaddress.com?

Comment: this plugin does not allow you to upload custom cert file